# How to remove the duplicated item sold by employee in power query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to remove the duplicated item sold by each and every employee.

For example in the screenshot above, there are 4 rows (apple, apple, orange, orange) for employee 1006, but since both apple and orange are duplicated, so I only need 2 rows (apple, orange) instead of 4 rows.

This process need to be done for each and every employee. The outcome will be something like this:

[image]

I'm not able to remove the duplicated item in column `item_sold` as it doesn't take care for `employee_id`.

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the columns headings of both columns and then on the Home ribbon, select the Remove Rows button and Remove Duplicates.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, never thought that the solution is straight forward